# Console Log Error onUpdate, Firebase Console

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I Have this function in Typescript deployed in my firebase console:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.initializeApp()


export const onEditModeUpdate = 
functions.firestore.document("Settings/ShiftsEditMode").onUpdate(change => { 
    if (change.after) {
        const after = change.after.data();
        const payload = {
            data: {
                temp: String(after.temp),
                conditions: String(after.conditions)
        }
    }
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("Settings/ShiftsEditMode", payload)
}
else {
    return null;
}
})
```

the deploy is correct but when i change the data i get an error in Console Log:

```
Error: Topic provided to sendToTopic() must be a string which matches the format "/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+".
at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:253:16)
at Messaging.validateTopic (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:964:19)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:650:19
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

any suggestion what i'm doing wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully the error message:

> Error: Topic provided to sendToTopic() must be a string which matches the format "/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+".

The string you've provided, "Settings/ShiftsEditMode" doesn't match the required pattern.  The pattern is saying that the string should start with "/topics/".  The rest of the string, which is the name of your topic, can only contain letters, numbers, underscore, dot, tilde, and percent.  The string you gave also doesn't match that pattern, as it contains an illegal slash.

Comment: i got this message noe meaning it's ok:  Function execution took 367 ms, finished with status: 'ok'